# Physics simulation won't run until the last frame of the timeline

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, timeline

I am making a rigid body physics simulation. It started out ending at 250 frames, but I later changed it to 400 frames.

The problem occurs when the whole animation stops at the 251st frame. Is there a certain setting for this or do I have to restart all over again?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you baked the sim?

Comment: It looks like the same problem has been answered here [rigid-simulation-freezes-at-frame-250
](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46820/rigid-simulation-freezes-at-frame-250?rq=1). Too few reputations for a comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rigid Simulation freezes at frame 250](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46820/rigid-simulation-freezes-at-frame-250)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The rigid body simulation does have it's own start and end.

[image]

In the 'Rigid Body World' settings you can change the simulation start and end.

Comment: For anyone wondering setting the cache start and end in the rigid body world while you already have objects with rigid body constraints in the scene will override their values.