# Why did my animation stop halfway in 3.4?

Tags: animation

I am still learning blender, and I decided to make my first animation. I decided to make it a ball rolling down a slope into a bowl. But, when I went to view my animation, it stopped halfway: [image: ball 1]

here is the next part:
[image: ball 2]
the ball does not even move. why is this? I really need some help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rigid Simulation freezes at frame 250](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46820/rigid-simulation-freezes-at-frame-250)

Comment: Hi TheSpaceWire, welcome. I'm leaving this post open in case it's _not_ a duplicate. But if Harry's link  works for you,  please comment to let us know. Thanks.