# Can't lengthen animation timeline

Tags: animation, timeline

I'm trying to do a simple animation, but for some reason the length of time is stuck on 250 frames, even if I put it to 800 (or whatever). I see this orange strip under the 250. The action stops at 250 frames, even though the timeline indicator keeps going.

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: if you google *animation stops at 250* u will get lots of search results. just increase the end frame cache in Rigid Body World properties https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6741/physics-are-not-simulated-past-a-certain-frame and if ur using cloth sim u also have to change the cache end frame in the cloth physics https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46820/rigid-cloth-simulation-freezes-at-frame-250. so basically up to 3 places u have to change the 250 end frame. (1) timeline (2) rigid body world (3) cloth physics if any

Comment: @moonboots Why that?

Comment: I wanted to test his file, didn't realize he was trying to do a physic simulation  ;)